# How to set dependencies in TeamWork app to cascade delays in one task into dates of other tasks?

Tags: pm-software, time-management

Let's say I have multiple tasks that are supposed to be taken care of one after another. Each has its own date of completion.

1. task 1 - will be completed on 15 march (1 day)
2. task 2 - will be completed on 17 march (2 days)
3. task 3 - will be completed on 18 march (1 day)
4. task 4 - will be completed on 21 march (3 day)

Suddenly `task 2` is delayed by two days. I would like `task 3` and `task 4`'s dates be changed accordingly.

Right now I use [teamwork](https://www.teamwork.com/). In [calendar view](https://d2.alternativeto.net/dist/s/teamwork_609820_full.jpg?format=jpg&width=1600&height=1600&mode=min&upscale=false), tasks are NOT connected to each other in any way. So if the date of one task changes, the rest stay the same. I need to manually move all tasks on the calendar.

Can such problem be taken care of in teamwork?

Comment: Microsoft project?

Comment: I never heard of teamwork, but every "project management" app I have come across can do that. Did you read their manual or help pages?

Comment: No clue which tool you are using, but I would make sure to make estimated end dates depended on the task(s) before it or something

Comment: Fairly trivial to do this in excel (or google sheets) as well.   Are you really asking how to do this _in teamwork_?

Comment: Please expand your question to describe what you've already tried, and why the [various help pages](https://support.teamwork.com/projects/search?query=dependencies) don't address your needs. In particular, there's a page specifically for [Changing Dates of Tasks with Dependencies](https://support.teamwork.com/projects/advanced/changing-dates-of-tasks-with-dependencies). If that doesn't help you, you'll need to explain *why not* to provide sufficient context.

Comment: Rephrased to focus on the teamwork app. Otherwise, the question itself needs to be rewritten. The subject and the question content are not aligned.